# How do i randomize a quiz in javascript while recording right and wrong answers?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the quiz to loop 5 times while recording the correct answer for each question before returning to start menu but I'm struggling to get it working
Any help with this will be much appreciated.

```
function cleartxt()
{
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('ans').innerHTML = ''", 3000);
}
var random = new Array(5);
var count = 0;
function next()
{
var store = 0;
do
{
store = (Math.round(Math.ceil(Math.random() * 40) -1));
}while(random.indexOf(store) > -1);
document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML = questions[store][0];
document.getElementById("rad1").innerHTML = questions[store][1];
document.getElementById("rad2").innerHTML = questions[store][2];
document.getElementById("rad3").innerHTML = questions[store][3];
document.getElementById("rad4").innerHTML = questions[store][4];
document.getElementById("image").src = images[store];
var radio = document.getElementsByName("rad");
while(store <= 5)
{   
    count++;
    if(store == 5)
        startMenu();
    if(radio[0].checked == true)
    {   
        if(questions[store][0] == questions[store][5])
            document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "Correct";
        else
            document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "Incorrect";
    }
    else if(radio[1].checked == true)
    {
        if(questions[store][1] == questions[store][5])
            document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "Correct";
        else 
            document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "Incorrect";
    }
    else if(radio[2].checked == true) 
    {
        if(questions[store][2] == questions[store][5])
            document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "Correct";
        else 
            document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "Incorrect";
    }
    else if(radio[3].checked == true)
    {
        if(questions[store][3] == questions[store][5])
            document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "Correct";
        else  
            document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "Incorrect";
    }
    else
        document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "Please select an answer!";
}
}
function startMenu()
{
    window.history.back();
}
```

Comment: Looks like your overwriting each one in the while loop ... if(questions[store][0] == questions[store][5] ... document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "Correct"; ...
    else if(radio[1].checked == true) ...
            document.getElementById("ans").innerHTML = "Correct"; ... when looping you need to save each item individually.so  "ans" id needs to change for each as these all are the same id.

Could also cut down the code by using something like count++; for the hard coded int's & tying it into the id in some way.

Also struggling to see why its looped 5x as-is (c no reason for it).

Comment: You also have questions[store][5] in each one so no other numbers are being used. You really should do this dynamically like  while {
if (questions[store][counterA] == questions[store][counterB] {...} ... counterA++; counterB++  } or even if (questions[store][counter] == questions[store][counter] counter++ if possible.

Comment: index [5]in the array is the correct answer that I was trying to compare it too.